# VBA Change Colour of Cell According to the number of Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to fill the cells according to the value of cells that I determined in another cell.

For instance,

- If I put `A33="5"` then fill green 5 cells in C column.
- If `A34="10"` then fill another 10 cells in C column at the same time.

When I change the values then I wish the number and color of cells in C column will be change accordingly.

I shared a sample picture as attach. If it is possible using with VBA?

[image: Sample Sheet]

Comment: Look into conditional formatting; it uses Excel standard tools, rather than requiring VBA.  If VBA is required, you could input the conditional formattign via VBA.  Another option, if conditional formatting is not desired, is to use Change_Events from VBA.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use a stacked bar chart?

Comment: @luuklag, do you have any examples for VBA code?

Comment: I'm confused by your image, the values don't match up with the number of blocks in each colour, as you described? In fact you even have additional colours which don't have values?

Comment: @Wolfie, I just shared the instance numbers. It does not matter I just find a vay to fill the cells according to the numbers given of another cell with VBA

Comment: There is no point giving an example if the example doesn't demonstrate the behaviour you want, it just makes things *less* clear! Why don't you use a [stacked bar chart](http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/how-to-easily-create-a-stacked-clustered-column-chart-in-excel/) in Excel? This avoids the need for VBA, and is built in. You're basically trying to code your own stacked bar chart...

Comment: @Wolfie; the question is not related with the stacked bar chart. The question is whether this is possible with VBA code or not? If yes I need an example codes to do this for understanding algorithm. Sorry for the mismatch between the examples and my words.

Comment: People here will be unlikely to write you code for free. The expectation is that you've given it a try, and have specific issues with the syntax, language, or something going wrong in your code. Yes it is possible, the reason that @Luuklag didn't elaborate on that is we expect you to do the heavy lifting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is applied to Column A ~ F.

**Sheet Event code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Range("a33", "f36"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        setColor Target.Column
    End If
End Sub
```

**Module code**

```
Sub setColor(col As Integer)
    Dim vDB, vColor
    Dim i As Integer, c As Integer, n As Integer

    vColor = Array(RGB(244, 185, 79), RGB(0, 180, 255), RGB(255, 54, 54), RGB(116, 211, 109))
    Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(32, col)).Interior.Color = RGB(36, 36, 36)
    vDB = Cells(33, col).Resize(4)
    For i = 1 To 4
        n = vDB(i, 1)
        c = c + n
        If IsEmpty(vDB(i, 1)) Then
        Else
            Cells(32, col).Offset(-c, 0).Resize(n).Interior.Color = vColor(i - 1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: ,Appreciate for your support. Really much appreciate

Comment: @SemihUral, Best of luck to  you.

Comment: ,thanks a lot. By the way, f I would like to increase the number,let assume that I put it 100 of A33 it will bring me debug.To avoid is and if I need to use 100 , which parts I need to modify?

Comment: @SemihUral, Change   If IsEmpty(vDB(i, 1)) Then  to If IsEmpty(vDB(i, 1)) Or c > 31 Then

Comment: If IsEmpty(vDB(i, 1)) Or c > 31 Then
        c = c - n

Comment: unfortunately I got some errors when I would like to increase the row nunmber. If you want. Just change this if condition is enough ? Should I change anything else for the rest of code ?

Comment: @Dr.Lee ,Below I share the update code . c=c-n did not work by the way. The thing I would like to do is increase the row numbers according to previous one.For previous one max 32 as you know

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub setColor(col As Integer)
    Dim vDB, vColor
    Dim i As Integer, c As Integer, n As Integer

    vColor = Array(RGB(244, 185, 79), RGB(0, 180, 255), RGB(255, 54, 54), RGB(116, 211, 109))
    Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(50, col)).Interior.Color = RGB(36, 36, 36)
    vDB = Cells(51, col).Resize(4)
    For i = 1 To 10
        n = vDB(i, 1)
        c = c + n
        If IsEmpty(vDB(i, 1)) Or c > 49 Then
        Else
            Cells(50, col).Offset(-c, 0).Resize(n).Interior.Color = vColor(i - 
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub setColor(col As Integer)
    Dim vDB, vColor
    Dim i As Integer, c As Integer, n As Integer

```
vColor = Array(RGB(244, 185, 79), RGB(0, 180, 255), RGB(255, 54, 54), RGB(116, 211, 109))
Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(50, col)).Interior.Color = RGB(36, 36, 36)
vDB = Cells(51, col).Resize(4)
For i = 1 To 4 '<~~ your if your range is "a51,f56", then it sould be 4 
n = vDB(i, 1)
    c = c + n
    If IsEmpty(vDB(i, 1)) Or c > 49 Then
    Else
        Cells(50, col).Offset(-c, 0).Resize(n).Interior.Color = vColor(i - 1)
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub